# Why std::gcd/lcm returns std::common_type_t<M, N> instead of auto?

Tags: c++

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/gcd):

```
template< class M, class N>
constexpr std::common_type_t<M, N> gcd(M m, N n);    (since C++17)
```

IIUC, to return right type,

```
template< class M, class N>
constexpr auto gcd(M m, N n);    (since C++17)
```

has the same effects and more elegent since c++14. `std::common_type_t` is just a workaround for `c++11`. But `std::gcd` is since `c++17`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifying that `std::gcd` returns "`auto`" wouldn't tell the implementers or the users of the standard API anything about what the function returns. Such specification wouldn't be useful.

Note that although the return type is specified to be `std::common_type_t<M, N>`, nothing prevents an implementation from using `auto` return type in their header, as long as the deduced type conforms to the specification.

---

> `std::common_type_t` is just a workaround for c++11

No. `std::common_type_t` alias for `std::common_type::type` was introduced in C++14. And it's not a "workaround".

Comment: Oops, it's my bad.

Comment: So, is it just the documentation and readability that common_type_t is still used, otherwise 'auto' will always work since c++14.

Answer (score 5):

`auto` indicates that the type should be inferred from the implementation. Putting `auto` on a documentation page *without* the implementation is not helpful to anyone reading the docs. On the other hand, `std::common_type_t` has well-defined behavior which is linked to straight from that documentation page, making it much more helpful.